# Yup JS validation schema depedencies

Tags: javascript, yup

I have a Yup Schema like...

```
code: Yup.string()
  .min(3, 'Must be at least 3 characters')
  .required('Code is required')
  .test('unique-code', 'Code is taken', productCodeValidator),
```

...where `.test('unique-code'` makes an API call that confirms a code is unique. I'd like to only fire that validator if the first two pass (min, required) but I couldn't find a Yup method that would do it.

I tried `.when` but that seems to only work with *sibling* fields, and I didn't see anything in the docs about not running subsequent validators when the earlier ones fail.

Any help appreciated, thanks!

Comment: Check this out: https://github.com/jquense/yup/issues/256

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> This is not currently possible because all validations run at the same time to maintain performance. There have been a number of other requests for this as well. For example, this is a similar request: #256 (https://github.com/jquense/yup/issues/256).
>   I am in favor of there being some way to handle some or all validations in some order/sequence.

References:

- https://github.com/jquense/yup/issues/503
- https://github.com/jquense/yup/issues/256

If you are using the schema in Formik you should define a custom validation function (https://itnext.io/simple-react-form-validation-with-formik-yup-and-or-spected-206ebe9e7dcc), and there you can validate inline the first conditions (for example using basicSchema.validate(data)) and if they return true you can validate the another condition.

Answer (score 0):

Yup allows you to customize a method to implement functions through `Yup.addMethod()`

So a wrapper method called `sequence` can be like this:

```
Yup.addMethod(Yup.string, 'sequence', function (funcList) {
  return this.test(async (value, context) => {
    try {
      for (const func of funcList) {
        await func().validate(value);
      }
    } catch ({ message }) {
      return context.createError({ message });
    }
    return true;
  });
});
```

Suppose you have an api called `uniqueUsername` for checking uniqueness which is an `axiosInstance`.
Then we can do this:

```
username: Yup.string().sequence([
        () => Yup.string().max(20).required('Username is required'), // check format first
        () => Yup.string().unique('Username is already taken', uniqueUsername),  // check uniqe via api
      ]),
```

The function `sequence` will check list in order.

PS: Code for `unique` function:

```
Yup.addMethod(Yup.string, 'unique', function (message, axiosInstance) {
  return this.test('unique', message, async (value) => {
    const { data } = await axiosInstance(value);
    return data;
  });
});
```